# Migrating Azure VM to a different location

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I have an Azure VM with a managed disk (which is not located in any storage account).

The VM is located in West US while it's resource group is located in West Europe.
I want to move the VM to West Europe as well.
Is there a way to move this VM to another location without generalizing it?

I saw that there's something called AzCopy, But I don't think that I can use it because my VM's disk is managed and it's not located in a storage account.

I can't use the recovery vaults because the resource group of the VM is located in the region where I want to move my VM to.
It shows the following error when I try to create a recovery vault in the same region:

> You cannot protect VMs from the same region as of the vault or vault’s resource group. In the event of a datacenter disruption, the vault or resource group also might not be available. Create (or use) a vault in a different region to protect these VMs.

And even If I could create the Vault, I still wouldn't find my VMs (to replicate) because they are in a different region than it's resource group.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an official tutorial explaining every step you need to take https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/resource-mover/move-region-within-resource-group.

Alternatively, I would create a new resource group with my desire location and create a new custom virtual network. Then move my VM to the new created resource group. click on the VM and go to networking, click on NIC public IP; disassociate it and associate the new custom VN.

#ps:
you might want to disassociate it first before moving to the new resource group.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Site Recovery

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/azure-to-azure-tutorial-migrate

> In addition to using the Azure Site Recovery service to manage and
>   orchestrate disaster recovery of on-premises machines and Azure VMs
>   for the purposes of business continuity and disaster recovery (BCDR),
>   you can also use Site Recovery to manage migration of Azure VMs to a
>   secondary region. To migrate Azure VMs, you enable replication for
>   them, and fail them over from the primary region to the secondary
>   region of your choice.

Comment: The thing is, I can't move the resource group because the resource group is already located at the specified location while the VM that's in the resource group is located in a different region.. So unfortunately I can't do that.

Comment: It looks like you can move the VM to a different resource group, migrate, then move back to the previous resource group?